# Microsoft HTTP SERVER API environment requirments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, http, visual-c++, server

I want my C++ application/process to be an HTTP server that listens to requests from another Java process. I am planning to use Microsoft's [HTTP Server API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-api-start-page) for this, but the documentation says:

> The HTTP Server API is supported on Windows Server 2003 operating systems and on Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2).

Does this mean that this only works on Windows Server 2003 but not later? I am using Microsoft Window Server 2019 standard.

Also, the documentation says:

> When you install the PSDK on drive C:\ of a local computer, the complete server sample application is installed at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\Samples\netds\http\server.

PSDK was replaced by Windows SDK a long time ago, and I am not able to find any sample in the Windows 10 SDK, and also I could not find any sample for the same on GIT.

I am afraid that the HTTP Server API is deprecated, or I am looking at older resources.

Is there any other solution for my problem?

Comment: `http.sys` APIs are pretty much universal on Windows these days.  You shouldn't have to worry about availability on desktop builds of Windows 10 and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements section (unless otherwise stated on the page) are always minimums. MS is very clear when something has been removed from the API (and even then is almost always a strong warning to quit using something rather than actually removing it).